# Pubnub memory management issue

Tags: objective-c, pubnub

I'm using an external library in my application (specifically https://github.com/jazzychad/CEPubnub) and I'm running into a memory management issue.  Following the initialization of the "CEPubnub" object, one must subscribe to a channel for receiving updates.  As such, I ended up writing the following code:

```
self.pubnub = [[[CEPubnub alloc] 
          publishKey:@"..." 
          subscribeKey:@"..." 
          secretKey:@"..." 
          sslOn:NO 
          origin:@"pubsub.pubnub.com"] autorelease];
//Set the channel for this holler
[self setPubnubChannel:[[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"channelprefix_"] autorelease]];
[pubnubChannel appendString:[event eventId]];
NSLog(@"Subscribing to the pubnubChannel: %@", (NSString *)[[pubnubChannel copy] autorelease]);
```

Whenever I end up running this application and load the view that this is called in, exit the view, load it again, I eventually end up causing a memory leak and the second line of code there is highlighted as the source of the problem (through my leaks instrument).

When I run Analyze, it also highlights the second line of code but says "potential leak of an object allocated on [line 1]", as though the first line is the problem.  In my viewDidUnload method and dealloc method, I make sure to release the pubnub property, but it still seems to leak and I'm dumbfounded.  Any ideas about what I should do?

Comment: I'm the author of CEPubNub. Without seeing the rest of the code for that class (the header file, the surrounding code from your snippet above, the init function, and the dealloc function at least) it will be really hard to tell exactly what is going on. Is 'pubnub' an instance variable? Is it synthesized? Happy to help, but more info is needed first.

Answer (score 2):

I learned this here: instruments is only showing you where the object that leaks is created. Follow that along the course of your code, you must be retaining one of these objects again elsewhere without another corresponding release.

If pubnub is a property, you are bypassing the setter by referring to the instance variable pubnub. If this is the case change it to self.pubnub and add autorelease. that should solve it.

```
self.pubnub = [[[CEPubnub alloc] 
      publishKey:@"..." 
      subscribeKey:@"..." 
      secretKey:@"..." 
      sslOn:NO 
      origin:@"pubsub.pubnub.com"] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks Dean, there's only one object here that's not being released by me manually as far as I know: the NSMutableArray.  Since pubnub is a pointer to the CEPubNub object being initialized, do you think I need something beyond [pubnub release]?

Comment: So I've confirmed the issue is with the pubnub object ... clearly I'm missing something there

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code. Something about pubnub has me puzzled. Is that an ivar for a property. That would explain it. If so, you should be referring to self.pubnub.

Comment: I added to my answer, where I think you need the autorelease. You could also release explicitly after passing it to the property if you prefer.  I am not sure if the other autoreleases were needed, I can't recall now what your first version was exactly but it did not seem to be a problem there.

Comment: If that still doesn't do it, use find and look everywhere you use pubnub. I must be getting retained again elsewhere.  Also, look at your dealloc method, there it should be [pubnub release] or self.pubnub = nil. Perhaps you have [self.pubnub release].

Answer (score 0):

CEPUBNUB WITH ARC

http://dashasalo.com/tag/pubnub/

Download Directly: http://dashasalo.com/wp-content/uploads/cepubnub/CEPubnub_ARC.zip

If you are struggling to make CEPubnub work with ARC then below is how I solved it for myself.

1. Remove all mentions of release and autorelease from all CEPubnub files. I had to remove quite a few but it was very straightforward.
2. Next step is to rename all methods that call init on object self to start with “init”. There will be a couple in CEPubnub.h /.m and CEPubnubRequest.h /.m. Don’t forget to find where these methods are called and update method names accordingly. For example, change the following:
3. If you then run Analyser it will say there is a potential memory leak in urlencode method. I had to assign the result of CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes to a new NSString object to get rid of the warning.